# Using same memory address ,but code taking 8 bytes extra in program memory?

Tags: c, optimization, embedded

I am using Atmel Studio for the atmega8 microcontroller. Here I have two options for accessing it's io ports.

1. I can use DDRB, PORTB, and PINB Macro


   MCU std ports macros

   ```
   #define _MMIO_BYTE(mem_addr) (*(volatile uint8_t *)(mem_addr))
   #define _SFR_IO8(io_addr) _MMIO_BYTE((io_addr) + __SFR_OFFSET)

   /* Port B */
   #define PINB     _SFR_IO8(0x16)
   #define DDRB     _SFR_IO8(0x17)
   #define PORTB    _SFR_IO8(0x18)
   ```

this is my simple test code

```
   #include <avr/io.h>

   #define F_CPU 1000000UL

   #include <util/delay.h>

   int main(void)
   {
    DDRB = 0x01;
    while (1)
    {
        PORTB = 0x01;
        _delay_ms(1000);
        PORTB = 0x00;
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
   }
```

> after successful compilation 
>
> Program Memory Usage  :   108 bytes   1.3 % Full 
> Data Memory Usage         :   0 bytes   0.0 % Full

2. Or I can use my own version 

   gpio.h\

#ifndef GPIO_H_ 
#define GPIO_H_

```
#include <avr/io.h>

typedef union {
    struct  
    {
        uint8_t pin0:1;
        uint8_t pin1:1;
        uint8_t pin2:1;
        uint8_t pin3:1;
        uint8_t pin4:1;
        uint8_t pin5:1;
        uint8_t pin6:1;
        uint8_t pin7:1;
    };
    struct {
        uint8_t lsb4:4;
        uint8_t msb4:4;
        };
        uint8_t pins;
}port_reg_t;

typedef struct  
{
    port_reg_t r;
    port_reg_t d;
    port_reg_t p;
}port_t;

#define bio    (*(volatile port_t *) (0x16 + __SFR_OFFSET))
```

#endif /* GPIO_H_ */

this is sample code

/*

- led.cpp
- 
- Created: 12-05-2022 14:59:53
- Author : HP
  */

  ```
   #include <avr/io.h>
   #define F_CPU 1000000UL
   #include <util/delay.h>

   #include "gpio.h"

   int main(void)
   {

       //DDRB = 0x01;
       //
       //
       //while (1)
       //{
       //PORTB = 0x01;
       //_delay_ms(1000);
       //PORTB = 0x00;
       //_delay_ms(1000);
       //}

   bio.d.pin0 = 1;

   while (1) 
   {
       bio.p.pin0 = 1;
       _delay_ms(1000);
       bio.p.pin0 = 0;
      _delay_ms(1000);

   }
  }
  ```

> after successful compilation 
>
> Program Memory Usage  :   116 bytes   1.4 % Full 
> Data Memory Usage         :   0 bytes   0.0 % Full

my question is,
why it's taking 8 bytes extra in program memory?

Comment: As for your problem, compilers and linkers for embedded systems are very good at creating map files where you can see exactly what memory areas are used and for what. If you look through them what do they say?

Comment: Most likely this is related to the use of bit-fields. There might be unmotivated padding added just for the heck of it. Take `sizeof` on each struct and see if it makes sense. Also, isn't `port_reg_t` supposed to be a union, not a struct?

Comment: The two code fragments do different things: the first works with whole bytes, the second works with bits. It is up to the compiler to optimize bit (and byte also...) access.

Comment: Nevermind the union comment, the awful, inconsistent code formatting confused me.

Comment: The reply to your question can be obtained by looking at the generated assembler. Perhaps you will see some inefficient way of coping with bits (I don't know/remember whether your MCU has special opcodes for single bits).

Comment: Also note that the order of bits inside an *allocation unit* (when you use `uint8_t` that's the allocation unit) is undefined. Typically it's either LSB to MSB or MSB to LSB, but the compiler can put these in any order it likes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I correct my second code it's a typo when I write the question, and thanks for correcting me

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica, in gpio.h ,let me update complete gpio.h file and main c file

Comment: This is why you should copy&paste your real code. That 100% avoids typos during writing the question.

Comment: you can use packed attribute to avoid padding

Comment: @SupportUkraine they are not different(use of memory) , I am not using any extra memory, I just want to trick the compiler to handle port pins directly. not like this DDRB = (1 << PINB0) | (1 << PINB1);

Comment: AVR gcc doesn't appear to insert any padding (which would be senseless, even though I wouldn't rule it out before testing).

Comment: @SupportUkraine and this trick is also useful in case of addressing if I write #define bio    (*(volatile port_t *) (0x16 + __SFR_OFFSET)), then bio access all three registers. DDRB, PORTB,and PINB

Comment: @Lundin , I think so, because embedded compilers are very sensitive to code optimization.

Comment: I agree that your struct is useful. BUT: the two programs do **different** things: Both set b0, but the first fragment also resets the other bits. Those are two different operations, and the compiler treats them differently.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica I agree with your comment, but this operation should be handled in data memory, not in program memory. correct me if I worng.

Comment: Also unrelated to the question, neither version should be using `int main (void)` as that may lead to extra dead space getting allocated. Use `void main (void)` and compile with `-ffreestanding`, it's not a PC.

Comment: You are wrong. You can set a register with, say, two opcodes (pseudo assembler): "mov a, 1;  mov reg, a". To set a single bit, you have to do maybe: "mov a,reg; or a,1; mov reg,a". This is the way a RISC does things, generally. If the compiler is not smart enough to use special opcodes for bit manipulation (which anyway would be more complex), then the operation takes three instructions instead of two.

Comment: @Lundin, int main (void), it's generated by Atmel studio.

Comment: @progmemcom So use a better IDE suitable for embedded systems.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the exact problem (with optimizations enabled). Which compiler (and version) did you exactly used and which optimizations? Did you enabled optimizations (eg `-O3`)?

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica , i think you are correct with this argument, thanks for letting me know=> If the compiler is not smart enough to use special opcodes for bit manipulation (which anyway would be more complex).

Comment: @Lundin, ok i will use mplabx with xc8 compiler.

Comment: @Lundin, Atmel studio *is* the IDE for Atmel MCUs (embedded)... this does not imply it is perfect though.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica , let me check this problem with xc8 compiler. I think Xc8 compiler has special opcode to handle bits.

Comment: In this case it's very likely just a matter of providing the correct compiler options. And not using auto-generated slop templates.

Comment: When you use bitfields you're saying to keep all the other bits the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you show, I can demonstrate your structs take 6 bytes more (in program space). I don't know why your compiler needs 8 bytes more instead of 6, but you can investigate the generated assembler (maybe you has to ask to generate it).

An assignation in C to an I/O register, like:

```
PORTB = 0x01;
```

is carried out by an AVR MCU in this way:

```
LDI   R1, 1      ; 16 bit instruction, 2 bytes
STS   PORTB, R1  ; again 2 bytes
```

For a total of 4 bytes. Instead of STS, sometimes it is possible to use OUT (see later), but it is an instruction anyway.

In your first program, you have 3 assignation like this.

In the second program, the compiler know it should operate on single bits, not whole bytes. To set a single bit in a I/O register, because the C program states:

```
bio.p.pin0 = 1;
```

the compiler has to generate:

```
LDS   R1, bio.p
ORI   R1, 1       ; <-- added instruction, 2 bytes
STS   bio.p, R1
```

That added instruction is the one that sets a bit leaving the other untouched. One instruction more is needed.

Now, in both programs there are 3 assignations like this and, in the second version, each one takes one more MCU instruction, for a total of 6 bytes.

The AVR MCU has instruction to manipulate single bits - in a register or in the I/O space. So the same effect to set a bit would have been made with a single:

```
SBI   PORTB, 0   ; <-- set bit 0 of PORTB
```

This single instruction does the same as the 3 previous LDS/ORI/STS! And it is to be noted that, if those instructions were used, the second program would be *shorter* than the former, not longer.

The problem is that those instructions (SBI/CBI) can be applied only to the first 32 addresses in their space. Now, depending also on the precise model of MCU, not all I/O registers reside in the first 32 addresses, so this instruction can not always be used, it depends on the target.

Probably your compiler chose to not use SBI/CBI because it is not able to understand they are safe in this case. Maybe if you turn on full optimization they will be used, or maybe you have to instruct the compiler to use them in this particular case.

About STS and OUT: STS can do everything OUT does, but they use different addresses. I don't understand why OUT (and its companion IN) exists, but surely there is a reason.

Comment: The advantages of the OUT instruction, compared to STS is that it is half the size and executes twice as fast.  The disadvantage of OUT is the limited address range that can be encoded. There is also a 16 bit version of STS which is only used on the reduced core subarch, this is more similar to OUT (but the register and address ranges differ between OUT and 16 bit STS).

Comment: Thank you @ccrause, at the time I wrote this answer I took a look at the AVR instruction set, but I didn't notice what are you pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You assume that both program do the **same**, but they do **not**. So this is the reason for the different memory usages.

The first program writes a complete byte to port B:

```c
    PORTB = 0x01;
```

The second program sets (resets) just one bit, leaving the other seven bits alone:

```c
    bio.p.pin0 = 1;
```

This is what happens "under the hood":

```c
    bio.p.pins = bio.r.pins | 0x01;
```

This is the comparable version with your header:

```c
    bio.p.pins = 0x01;
```

Comment: I know how they work, please read the question again.It's about memory not about working

Comment: @progmemcom How to answer this yourself: build program 1, save the map file. Build program 2, save the map file. Examine both files in your favourite diff tool.